# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Counter' and 'int' - Bag of Words

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, bag

I'm attempting to plot my bag of word for selecting a suitable number of words to use to train my regression algorithm. When I try to plot it though, I get an error.

This is my code for making the bag of words:

```
df['BOW'] = df.Review2.str.split().apply(Counter)
df['BOW'].head()
```

This is the code for the plotting (I use `seaborn`):

```
sns.distplot(df['BOW'].sum())
```

and this is the error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Counter' and 'int'

this is how my bag of words looks like:

> 0    {'good': 2, 'need': 1, 'change': 1, 'virgils':...
>
> 1    {'new': 3, 'favorite': 2, 'give': 1, 'delightf...
>
> 2    {'red': 3, 'sauce': 2, 'favorite': 1, 'enjoy':...
>
> 3    {'quality': 1, 'fantastic': 1, '1800s': 1, '21...
>
> 4    {'red': 1, 'first': 1, 'time': 1, 'try': 1, 'l...

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)
is definitely a good read.

Answer (score 2):

You're generating `Counter` objects.

```
>>> Counter('some words here are some repeated words'.split())
Counter({'words': 2, 'repeated': 1, 'some': 2, 'here': 1, 'are': 1})
```

While you can `sum()` counter objects, ...

```
>>> Counter('aaabb') + Counter('abc')
Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 1})
```

... you can't divide them to calculate average:

```
>>> (Counter('aaabb') + Counter('abc')) / 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Counter' and 'int'
```

That's what your plotting library seems to be doing? Maybe you want to remove that column from the graph....

Comment: Ok I get why it doesn't work now. But I need to plot these items in order to see the most frequent ones since I need to select a subset of those for performing a regression. What do you mean by 'delete that column from the graph'?